# Is it possible to use two different versions of same package in buildroot?

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

Currently used packages in my system are..

**buildroot-2011.02**

**libpng-1.4.5**

**autoconf-2.65**

**python-2.7.1**

I am trying to upgrade **Libpng** from version-1.4.5 to version-1.6.8.

But the newer version of **Libpng** requires **Autoconf 2.68** or higher.

If I update **Autoconf** to 2.68, **Python 2.7.1** fails which requires older version of **Autoconf**.

So I have to update **Python** to higher version which supports **Autoconf 2.68**.

But this is creating whole lot of problems for me because Python is used in many other modules which also fails to build.

Other solution I could think is keeping both versions of Autoconf i.e. 2.68 and 2.65
and I have to make sure **Libpng** uses **Autoconf 2.68** and **Python** uses **Autoconf 2.65**.

Is it possible to do this? Is there any alternate solution to this problem?

Comment: Btw. why do you need autoconf? If you look at the latest version in BR, libpng uses `configure` scripts only.

Comment: Right..but there is a version check in libpng because of which my build was failing. so i just ramoved that check and build is continuing now.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the newest Buildroot version and use [BR2_EXTERNAL](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#outside-br-custom) feature. This way you'll keep your own packages/configuration separately from BR tree. So you can update BR whenever you like and your stuff still will be working.

```
mkdir /home/user/my_bsp
cd /home/user/
git clone git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
cd buildroot
make BR2_EXTERNAL=/home/user/my_bsp help
```

Now your BR tree will be looking for configuration and packages in `/home/user/my_bsp`

Comment: Thank you. I cannot use latest version of buildroot. However I can add this feature to current buildroot and try how it goes.

Comment: Why can't you update? You will spend a *lot* more time backporting a crazy amount of stuff than updating. Why would you invest time/money bringing new things into the past, rather than taking your stuff into the future?